# how to add error document for local site (where index is not in doc root) and live site both in one .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

In the local *dev* site the index.html and error html are in /subfolder/main/

Therefore:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /subfolder/main/error.php?e=400
```

On the live site they are located in the document root so:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
```

The problem is that I can't copy the .htaccess direct from one to the other and I always need to modify the paths if that happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single htaccess, you can't do this since it works identical to a `<Directory>` container. Additionally, the `ErrorDocument` directive doesn't have and conditionals. What you need to do is create a second htaccess file with *only* an error document directive, which will override the one declared in the document root.

Everything else in the document root's htaccess file should still apply.